# The Legrand Orange Book back matter

Tags: templates, appendices, book-design

Using the [Legrand Orange Book template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book), I would like to get the appendix to be renumbered from A.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum, fancyhdr}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

\usepackage{avant} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true,sorting=none,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

 \defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[font={color=ocre,bf},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{myformula/.style={
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  %colback=ocre!10,
  colback=mygray,
  colframe=ocre,
  boxrule=0.8pt,
  left=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  highlight math style={
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colback=mygray,
    colframe=red.
    }
  }
}

\newenvironment{spread}[1]{%
  \advance\jot#1% indeed
  }{%
\ignorespacesafterend
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\newcommand\ph\mlplaceholder
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\phOpDelim@mlpr{$\langle$}
\renewcommand\phClDelim@mlpr{$\rangle$}
\makeatother

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font={color=ocre,bf,it},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}
\newcommand{\figref}[2][]{% \figref[<sub-figref>]{<figref>}
  \textcolor{ocre}{\bfseries\emph{\figurename\,\ref{#2}#1}}}

\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex 

\input{structure_nofrtmatter}

\newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\frontmatter

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\vspace*{9cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
Test Book\par
\vspace*{1cm}
{\Huge Author}\par 
\endgroup

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\tableofcontents 

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Two}
\section{One}
\lipsum

\backmatter
\chapter{Appendix 1}
\section{One}
\lipsum

\chapter{Appendix 2}
\section{One}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Currently, the `\backmatter` chapters keeps the numbering from the last `\mainmatter` chapter. How can I go about renumbering the Appendix chapters using Alpha Chapter deisgnators. The first Appendix chapter should show A. Appendix 1 and the section numbering should start from A.1 etc.

Comment: I had to google for "legrand orange book" it might have been good to give a link (although actually I suppose that source isn't relevant to the question)

Comment: You've included some packages twice. And some definitions look weird

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: See the better version at the end of this answer.

Just use `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}` after `\backmatter`. But in my point of view, `\backmatter` is of no use here.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum, fancyhdr}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

\usepackage{avant} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true,sorting=none,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

 \defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[font={color=ocre,bf},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{myformula/.style={
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  %colback=ocre!10,
  colback=mygray,
  colframe=ocre,
  boxrule=0.8pt,
  left=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  highlight math style={
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colback=mygray,
    colframe=red.
    }
  }
}

\newenvironment{spread}[1]{%
  \advance\jot#1% indeed
  }{%
\ignorespacesafterend
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\newcommand\ph\mlplaceholder
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\phOpDelim@mlpr{$\langle$}
\renewcommand\phClDelim@mlpr{$\rangle$}
\makeatother

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[font={color=ocre,bf,it},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}
\newcommand{\figref}[2][]{% \figref[<sub-figref>]{<figref>}
  \textcolor{ocre}{\bfseries\emph{\figurename\,\ref{#2}#1}}}

\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\makeindex 

%\input{structure_nofrtmatter}

\newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\frontmatter

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\vspace*{9cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
Test Book\par
\vspace*{1cm}
{\Huge Author}\par 
\endgroup

%\chapterimage{chapter_head_1}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\tableofcontents 

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Two}
\section{One}
\lipsum

\backmatter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\chapter{Appendix 1}
\section{One}
\lipsum

\chapter{Appendix 2}
\section{One}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

**Update** with some improvements, replacing `\backmatter` by an `\appendix` command with slightly changed chapter header settings. 
`\appendix` switches to alpha counting by macro design.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} 
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

\usepackage{avant} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage[refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true,sorting=none,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[font={color=ocre,bf},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{myformula/.style={
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  %colback=ocre!10,
  colback=mygray,
  colframe=ocre,
  boxrule=0.8pt,
  left=2pt,
  right=2pt,
  highlight math style={
    arc=0pt,
    outer arc=0pt,
    colback=mygray,
    colframe=red.
    }
  }
}

\newenvironment{spread}[1]{%
  \advance\jot#1% indeed
}{%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\newcommand\ph\mlplaceholder
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\phOpDelim@mlpr{$\langle$}
\renewcommand\phClDelim@mlpr{$\rangle$}
\makeatother

\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\figref}[2][]{% \figref[<sub-figref>]{<figref>}
  \textcolor{ocre}{\bfseries\emph{\figurename\,\ref{#2}#1}}}

\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\makeindex 

%\input{structure_nofrtmatter}

\newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{%
\@mainmattertrue
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
}{%
}{\typeout{success}}{}%
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{%
  \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip 20\p@
}{%
  \huge\bfseries \thechapter. #1
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip 20\p@  % can be reduced!
}{\typeout{success}}{}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\frontmatter

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\vspace*{9cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
Test Book\par
\vspace*{1cm}
{\Huge Author}\par 
\endgroup

%\chapterimage{chapter_head_1}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\tableofcontents 

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\index{sometest}

\section{One}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Two}
\section{One}
\lipsum

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix 1}
\section{One}
\lipsum

\chapter{Appendix 2}
\section{One}
\index{sometextfromappendix2}
\lipsum

\cleardoublepage
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
\setindexname{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will update the code with the `A. Appendix 1` etc. requirement

Comment: actually, appendices are usually *not* included in `\backmatter`, at least in the books i've dealt with.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That's why I removed the `\backmatter` stuff in the second example and replaced it with `\appendix --> this makes the chapter counter reformatting unnecessary